# printing 5 words before and after a specific word in a file in python

Tags: python, nlp

I have a folder which contains some other folders and these folders contain some text files. (The language is Persian). I want to print 5 words before and after a keyword with the keyword in the middle of them. I wrote the code, but it gives the 5 words in the start and the end of the line and not the words around the keyword. How can I fix it?

Hint: I just write the end of the code which relates to the question above. The start of the code is about the opening and normalizing the files.

```
def c ():
y = "آرامش"
text= normal_text(folder_path) # the first function to open and normalize the files
for i in text:
    for line in i:
        if y in line:
            z = line.split()
            print (z[-6], z[-5],
                   z[-4], z[-3],
                   z[-2], z[-1], y,
                   z[+1], z[+2],
                   z[+3], z[+4],
                   z[+5], z[+6])
```

what I expect is something like this:

word word word word word keyword word word word word word

Each sentence in a new line.

Comment: What if the keyword is the 3rd word? Do we output just 3 before, or 5 including from previous lines?

Comment: In this case, just 3 before

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
def c():
    y = "آرامش"
    text= normal_text(folder_path) # the first function to open and normalize the files
    for i in text:
        for line in i:
            split_line = line.split()
            if y in split_line:
                index = split_line.index(y)
                print (' '.join(split_line[max(0,index-5):min(index+6,le
n(split_line))]))
```

Assuming the keyword must be an exact word.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the words indices based on your keyword's index. You can use `list.index()` method in order to get the intended index, then use a simple indexing to get the expected words:

```
for f in normal_text(folder_path):
    for line in f:
      if keyword in line:
          words = line.split()
          ins = words.index(keyword)
          print words[max(0, ind-5):min(ind+6, len(words))]
```

Or as a more optimized approach you can use a generator function in order to produce the words as an iterator which is very much optimized in terms of memory usage.

```
def get_words(keyword):
    for f in normal_text(folder_path):
        for line in f:
            if keyword in line:
                words = line.split()
                ins = words.index(keyword)
                yield words[max(0, ind-5):min(ind+6, len(words))]
```

Then you can simply loop over the result for print or etc.

```
y = "آرامش"
for words in get_words(y):
    # do stuff
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It splits the words. Then it calculates the amount to show before and after (with a minimum of however much is left, and a maximum of 5) and shows it.

```
words = line.split()
if y in words:
    index = words.index(y)
    before = index - min(index, 5)
    after = index + min( len(words) - 1 - index, 5) + 1    
    print (words[before:after])
```

Comment: Thanks a lot everybody.

Comment: @suneye Please accept one with the grey tick below the down arrow if it solved your issue.

Comment: Of course all the answers here are acceptable. thank you

Comment: @suneye If you click the tick on one of them it will mark the question as solved